# wirecloud default workspace

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I've got my own wirecloud instance running.

I've developed a set of specific widgets and operators, but as I register a new user I have to manually load each component.

It's possible to configure it so users can have a default workspace?

How?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, it's not possible to set up a default workspace for new user. See this [ticket](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/issues/50) for more details.

In the other hand, it's possible to install components for all the users of your WireCloud instance:

- You can use the command line interface (doc) and upload the resources for all the users:

  ```
  $ python manage.py addtocatalogue --public mycomponents/*.wgt
  ```
- Or your can make use of the Django's admin panel:

  - Open it:

    [image]
  - Go to the *Catalogue Resources* section:

    [image: Catalogue Resource section]
  - Select a component:

    [image: catalogue resource select]
  - And make it available to all the users of your WireCloud instance:

    [image: make component public]